# Adding own menu function to wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I want to replace the standard menu(on wordpress) with a menu i created(http://jsfiddle.net/nxy9jkdx/1/). Im new to using wordpress and still learning. I was wondering if anyone could take me through what files i edit and how i go about adding my own code.

http://jsfiddle.net/nxy9jkdx/1/ (code)

Ive managed to do it! heres the code!

```
            <div id="menu" class="menu-icon">
            <img onclick="javascript:displaymenu()" src="http://wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2014/10/menu.png"/>
            </div>
            <div id="nav-bar" class="clearfix">
                <nav>
                    <div id="menu-icon" class="mobile-button"><span><?php _e('Menu', 'themify'); ?></span></div>
                        <div id="menu-exit">
                            <img id="exiticon" class="menu-icon-exit" onclick="javascript:closemenu()" src="http://wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2014/10/exit.png"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

<script language="javascript">
function displaymenu() {
            var showme= document.getElementById("nav-bar");
            showme.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
function closemenu() {
            var hideme= document.getElementById("nav-bar");
            hideme.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

</script>
```

The only problem is that when a link in the menu is clicked i want to run the js function: closemenu().

can anyone guide me to what file and code i should be editing to achieve this.

Comment: You don't. You properly use the [Navigation Menus API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus), and add your styles to a stylesheet.

Comment: So i cant add the menu(as above) to my wordpress site?

Comment: Sure, you could. But the right way to do it is register a menu that is editable via the admin, using the API. You'd then add your styles to a registered stylesheet. It's bad practice to add hard-coded navigation items to WordPress templates.

Comment: Do you know theme integration in wordpress ?

Comment: Ive figured out how to do it(see edits above) however im not sure how to run the closemenu() function when one of the menu links are clicked. Can anyone help to what file & section i should be looking at?